# Any performance issues with a SATA to PATA adapter for a 2nd hard disk for my laptop?

Tags: sata, adapter, pata

I am considering buying a SATA to PATA HDD Hard Drive caddy adapter
for my laptop. That would be something like [this one](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/SATA-to-PATA-Second-2nd-HDD-SSD-Hard-Drive-caddy-Adapter-for-DELL-INSPIRON-1525?item=300801944877&cmd=ViewItem&_trksid=p5197.m7&_trkparms=algo=LVI&itu=UCI&otn=4&po=LVI&ps=63&clkid=2935768609874244882). Should I
expect a lower performance when using a SATA HDD with a PATA 
adapter? If so, do you think it is going to be a significantly lower 
performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pata is inherently lower performance than Sata, so there will be some performance degradation with the adapter itself (there is some sort of chip in the enclosure doing the Pata>Sata translation and may cause further degradation depending on the quality), maybe someone else can comment on the bus architecture of the Pata drive slot in the laptop itself, there may be some there also.

In the end I am sure it will work just fine and are far better than usb, but you almost have to do your own testing to see what the actual sustained read-write performance will be.

Comment: However, if the aim is to provide some notebook that has the parallel IDE interface with extra disk space, then I believe that this tandem will perform equally to the native PATA drive. What you think?

Comment: I think a modern SATA drive will outperform an old PATA drive. While there will be some extra latency in the adaptor I still expect "SATA-Drive+convertor+PATA motherboard" to be faster than "OLD PATA drive + PATA motherboard".  Ofc, a lot depeneds in the speed of the translation and which drives are compared.

Comment: @Hennes then we may say that the OP will not see the performnace degradation but perhaps (s)he will see the increase

Comment: @Serge no way to know without testing on the actual hardware combination.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.. I start getting the idea. As I replied in the above comment, I also have a free "expresscard" slot. I googled around and found that there _are_ expresscard sata adapters (e.g. [this one](http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Express-Controller-Adapter-ECESATA254F/dp/B004NO0KNG/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1351026537&sr=8-4&keywords=esata+expresscard)).

As it was said, no way to know without testing, but do you have any comments regarding the sata to pata adapter vs expresscard scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You will not get the full benefits of a SATA hard disk if you use a SATA to PATA converter.

Instead if you have a spare PCI slot available, I would recommend using a [SATA to PCI converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000DZFJI) which will give much better performance. I myself used a SATA to PCI converter to connect my new SATA hard disk to my old Dell machine which supported only PATA.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. I googled around and in my understanding (I don't know that much about hardware) I do not have a spare pci slot available on my dell inspiron 1525. I do have an "express card" slot available though and I did find "esata expresscards" around. Would that be a better option for me than the cd caddy, you think?